# How to solve in terms of k the following equation?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

How to solve in terms of k the following:

\begin{equation}
200=20 \times \frac{1-(1+k)^{-4}}{k}+\frac{228.59}{(1+k)^4}
\end{equation}

Any help highly appreciated

Comment: I doubt there is a great closed formula.  Numerical methods work, of course.  There's a solution near $k\sim .1295$ for instance.

Comment: What have you tried? Avoid no-clue question: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: @Saad I don't know how to start...

Comment: Does $228,59$ stand for $228.59$?

Comment: Yes I edited the original post

Comment: In many countries around the world, some of them in Europe, they use comma , as in some other use decimal period (point) . Thus, we can write  $\;\cfrac32=1.5=1,5\;$ , depending where we are.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives some kind of results: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=200%3D20+%5Ctimes+%5Cfrac%7B1-%281%2Bk%29%5E%7B-4%7D%7D%7Bk%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B228.59%7D%7B%281%2Bk%29%5E4%7D

Comment: @DonAntonio - duly noted.  Thanks.

Comment: @Gina where is 228.59 comming from? Is it only an approximate value, or the exact?

Answer (score 2):

Transform $1+k \rightarrow z$, which gives

$$a=c\frac{1-z^{-4}}{z-1}+\frac{d}{z^4}$$ where $a=200,c=20,d=228.59$, since these constants do not have any apparent bearing to the problem.

Then, multiplying $z^4$ throughout, we have $$az^4 = c\dfrac{z^4-1}{z-1} + d \implies az^4-cz^3-cz^2-cz-(c+d)=0$$

which being a quartic equation, we actually know how to find it's roots by [Ferrari's method](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ferrari%27s_Method).

The roots you find will be the values of $z=1+k$, so remember to subtract $1$ to get your answer.

Comment: That is not a biquadratic equation as it has terms of degree $\;1.\.3\;$ . That's just a quartic equation.

Comment: @DonAntonio I apologize, my bad. I meant a degree 4 equation only, I wasn't aware of the difference between the terminologies of quartic and biquadratic. Thank you for the correction, I learnt this today. :D

Answer (score 2):

Consider
$$\begin{equation}
y=20 \times \frac{1-(1+k)^{-4}}{k}+\frac{22859}{100(1+k)^4}
\end{equation}$$

Use Taylor series around $k=0$ gives
$$y=\frac{30859}{100}-\frac{27859 }{25}k+\frac{26859 }{10}k^2-\frac{26359
   }{5}k^3+\frac{182413}{20}k^4+O\left(k^5\right)$$ Using series reversion leads to
$$k=-t+\frac{134295}{55718}t^2-\frac{10691793215 }{1552247762}t^3+\frac{3664144204520905
  }{172976281606232}t^4+O\left(t^5\right)$$ where $t=\frac{25 }{27859}\left(y-\frac{30859}{100}\right)$.

Making $y=200$ leads to
$$k=\frac{3430730696218578011844685765476873}{26674028799972940581873746705242112}\approx 0.1286$$ while the exact solution, obtained using Ferrari's method for quartics, is $0.1295$

Another thing which could be done is to approximate $y$ by a $[2,2]$ Padé approximant which would be
$$y\sim\frac {\frac{30859}{100}-\frac{12973524100179}{66968788100}k+\frac{16134307928979
   }{133937576200} k^2} {1+\frac{1997920043 }{669687881}k+\frac{3294721405 }{1339375762}k^2}$$ Solving the quadratic for $y=200$ would give $k\approx 0.129504$  to be compared to $0.129497$.

Comment: Whoa. Those are some big numbers :D

Comment: @K.defaoite. What do you want to do if numerical methods are not used ?  This looks like a finance problem where you need to find the interest rate. Cheers :-)